# Solution verification —— Proof of the Riemann mapping theorem using Perron's solution of the Dirichlet problem.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

This is exercise 7-73 of Krantz & Greene's Function Theory of One Complex Variable :

Complete the following outline to show that Perron's solution of the Dirichlet problem can be used to give another proof of the Riemann mapping theorem. Fix a simply connected domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$. For simplicity, let us assume that $\Omega$ is bounded and that the boundary of $\Omega$ consists of a single $C^1$ curve. (You are authorized to take for granted any "intuitively obvious" topological properties that you need here.) Fix a point $P\in\Omega$.

(a)  Let $\Gamma(z)=\log |z-P|.$

> Nothing to do here.

(b) Let $\phi$ be the restriction of $\Gamma$ to the boundary of $\Omega$. Let $m$ be the solution of the Dirichlet problem with boundary data $-\phi$.

> Nothing to do here.

(c) Set $u(z)=\Gamma(z)+m(z).$ Then $u$ is harmonic, except at $P$. [The function $u(z)$, which of course depends on the choice of $P$, is called the "Green's function" for $\Omega$; the usual notation for the function that we call $u(z)$ is $G(z,P$)].

> Since $m$ is harmonic in $\Omega$, it suffices to consider $\Gamma(z)$. For $z_0\in\Omega\setminus\{P\}$, there exists a neighborhood $B(z_0,r)\subset\Omega\setminus\{P\}$ on which $\log(z-P)$ is well defined and holomorphic, thus $\log|z-P|=\Re \log(z-P)$ is harmonic in $B(z_0,r)$. Therefore $\Gamma$ is harmonic except at $P$ and so is $u$.

(d)The integral $\int -\partial u/\partial y \,dx+\partial u/\partial x\,dy$ is path-independent modulo $2\pi$, that is, $\int_{\gamma}$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ for any closed $\gamma$ lying in $\Omega\setminus \{P\}$, the multiple depending on $\gamma$.

> First, we consider the case $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve around $P$. Let $C$ be a small circle centered at $P$ with radius $R$, such that $R < 2^{-1}dis(P,\gamma)$. Denote by $U$ the domain with boundary $\partial U=\gamma \cup C$. Then we have $$\int_{\partial U} -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\,dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\,dy=\int_U \Delta u\,dxdy =0$$
> by Green's formula and $u$ is harmonic in $U$. Therefore, $\int_{\gamma}=\int_{C}$ (both with positive orientation). To compute the latter one, we may assume that $P=0$ for simplicity. Note that $\log r=\log(x^2+y^2)/2$ and $m$ is harmonic, we have
> $$\int_C=\int_C \big(-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\big)\cdot \big(\frac{y}{R},\frac{x}{R}\big)\,d\sigma_C=\frac{1}{R}\cdot 2\pi R=2\pi.$$
> where $\sigma_C$ is the submanifold measure on $C$. From which we derive that for the general case, $\int_{\gamma}=n\cdot 2\pi$, where $n$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ around the point $P$.

(e) The function $f(x,y)=\exp [u+i (\int -\partial u/\partial y \,dx+\partial u/\partial x\,dy) ]$ is well defined and holomorphic. here the value of the integral at a point $Q\in\Omega$ means the integral from some fixed base point $P_0\neq P$ to $Q$ along any curve from $P_0$ to $Q$, this integral being defined up to multiples of $2\pi$.

> Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ be two curves from $P_0$ to $Q$, consider the integral along these curves, we have
> $$\int_{\gamma_1}-\int_{\gamma_2}=\int_{\gamma_1\cdot \overline{\gamma_2}}=n\cdot 2\pi $$ since $\gamma_1\cdot \overline{\gamma_2}$ is a closed curve. Therefore $f(x,y)$ is well defined. To see $f(x,y)$ is holomorphic, we should calculate the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\int -\partial u/\partial y\,dx +\partial u/\partial x\,dy \Big)\Big|_Q$. By definition, let $C_h$ be the horizontal curve from $Q$ to $Q+(h,0)$, and parametrized by $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2,t\mapsto Q+t(h,0)$. Then we have $C_h'(t)=(h,0)$ and thus
> $$\int_{C_h} =\int_0^1 \big( -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\big)\big|_{C_h(t)}\cdot C_h'(t)\,dt=h\int_0^1 -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\big|_{C_h(t)}\,dt $$
> therefore $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\int -\partial u/\partial y\,dx +\partial u/\partial x\,dy \Big)\Big|_Q=\lim_{h\to 0} \int_0^1 -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\big|_{C_h(t)}\,dt=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\big|_Q$$ by continuity. Similarly, we have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(\int -\partial u/\partial y\,dx +\partial u/\partial x\,dy \Big)\Big|_Q=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\big|_Q $$
> Then we have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}f=\frac{1}{2}f \big[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\frac{1}{i}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+i\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})\big]=0$$ that is, $f$ is holomorphic.

(f) Verify that $f$ takes boundary limits of modulus $1$ at all boundary points of $\Omega$. Conclude that $f\colon \Omega\to \mathbb{D}$.

> We have $|f|=\exp(u)$. Since $\Gamma(z)$ is subharmonic in $\Omega$, we have $u(z)$ is subharmonic. Note that $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ by the construction of $m$, we have $u\leq 0$ in $\Omega$. So we have $f\colon \Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, and f takes boundary limits of modulus $1$ at all boundary points of $\Omega$ by the continuity of $u$. Open mapping theorem gives $f\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{D}$.

(g) Use the argument principle to check that $f$ is one-to-one and onto.

> Now, we have $f\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic, and $f$ has exactly one zero in $\Omega$, that is, the point $P$. Since $f$ maps $\partial \Omega$ into $\mathbb{D}$, then for any $|w|<1$, there exists a smooth curve contained in $\Omega$ and $|f(z)|>|w|$ on the curve. Then, by Rouche's theorem, $f(z)-w$ has exactly one zero in the interior of the curve. Since the curve can be chosen to be arbitrarily close to $\partial \Omega$, we have $f(z)-w$ has exactly one zero in $\Omega$. So we have done.